# resolution on dell xps 13

Tags: resolution

I use a dell xps 13 laptop and I have issues to see the characters, they are very small in all tools that I use. Is there a way to see all app in a best way ?

If I decrease the resolution the icons and the bar see really bad.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of the XPS 13. The newest release XPS 13 9343 has two resolutions. 1920x1080 for non-touch and 3200 x 1800 for the touch model.

Comment: I have 1920 x 1080 model and I can't imagine how can be the 3200 x 1800 model.

Answer (score 2):

You can using scaling; though not all apps pay attention to the scaling options of the OS.

settings > display > scale for menu and title bars.

you could also change the LCD resolution to a non-native resolution.

settings > display > resolution drop down.

[image]

Comment: I did it. But in this way many sites are viewed blurry. I don't know what is the best setting for this laptop.

Comment: I solved the problem in this way for my XPS13 9343 ( touch screen), but still the login screen keeps the old wrong (too small) resolution. Any idea about how to transfer this scaling to lightdm?