# Resolution Too High for Programs on XPS 13

Tags: dell, fonts, 15.10, display-resolution, xps

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 (upgraded from 15.04) on the XPS13 (9343, Windows version).
As this ultrabook has a very high resolution touch-screen (3200x1800), I followed some useful threads on how to fix the resolution problems.
As an example, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635994/resolution-on-dell-xps-13/639698#639698) it is simply explained how to increase the font size in UNIX, and that work perfectly for all UNIX's windows.
It worked also for Firefox's text, bar and tabs' names, but the "check boxes" and some other features are still tiny.

An additional problem that I can't solve is that the font/objects size in 
the programs I use is still very small (see example below).
Also, my cursor has usually a normal size when moving on UNIX's windows, but when it goes on some other programs' windows, it becomes way smaller (you can see the black arrow in the Skype window).

Any hint about it?
I'll be happy to provide more details if needed.

[image: Difference in resolution of font/objects between UNIX's windows (appearance) and external programs (Skype, GIMP).]

Comment: I have the same problem on 15.04, I hoped 15.10 will have these hidpi issues solved... So there is no progress yet?

Comment: @plopp Isn't there any other solution than lowering the resolution to  2048x1152 with a scaling factor of 1,12?

Comment: same problem in xps13 with 18.04

Answer (score -2):

Open up your terminal and type this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

It sets the `Window scaling factor`, which is a factor used to scale windows on high-dpi screens, to 2.

Comment: Modifying the scaling factor does not solve the issue...